# Get user UID after user registering

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

How to get user UID after user registration. I'm trying to do with getCurrentUser method but it ends up always null. Here is the method :

```
  String userId;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getCurrentUser();
  }

  getCurrentUser() async {
    FirebaseUser firebaseUser = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
    setState(() {
      userId = firebaseUser.uid;
    });
  }
```

And here is the button when users wants to register and the data that user input will send to Firebase. But the userId always null.

```
Container(
                  height: 45.0,
                  width: 270.0,
                  child: RaisedButton(
                    child: Text('SIGN UP'),
                    onPressed: () async {
                      setState(() {
                        showSpinner = true;
                      });
                      try {
                        final newUser =
                            await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
                                email: email, password: password);
                        _firestore.collection('UserAccount').add({
                          'uid': userId,
                          'Email Address': email,
                          'Full Name': nama,
                          'Phone Number': phoneNumber,
                        });
                        if (newUser != null) {
                          Navigator.pushNamed(context, HomePage.id);
                        }
                        setState(() {
                          showSpinner = false;
                        });
                      } catch (e) {
                        print(e);
                      }
                    },
                  ),
                ),
```

If I try to register with the code above, this error showed up.

[image]

Thank you for anyone who trying to help :(

Comment: null means there is definitely no user signed in at the time you called currentUser.  Are you expecting it to wait until the user is finally signed in?

Comment: I'm expecting after the user registered, Firebase collect the uid too not only the name and email address, which both of it from user input. Because the uid comes from Firebase, i don't know how to get it and inside the field uid always null

Comment: are you calling getCurrentUser before registering?

Comment: @PeterHaddad I think I did because I don't know how to access it.

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the `uid` after registering:

```
 final newUser =
   await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
   email: email, password: password);
 _firestore.collection('UserAccount').add({
                          'uid': newUser.user.uid,
                          'Email Address': email,
                          'Full Name': nama,
                          'Phone Number': phoneNumber,
                        });
```

`newUser` should return a value of type `AuthResult` and inside `AuthResult` it has a field of type [`FirebaseUser`](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/firebase_auth/firebase_auth/lib/src/auth_result.dart#L18), therefore you can use `newUser.user.uid`.

---

If you want to get the data from the document based on the user id, then I recommend to do the following:

```
 final newUser =
   await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
   email: email, password: password);
 _firestore.collection('UserAccount').document(newUser.user.uid).setData({
                          'Email Address': email,
                          'Full Name': nama,
                          'Phone Number': phoneNumber,
                        });
```

Comment: the firebaseuser isn't used anywhere? I already tried your code and it works, but I still don't understand how it works

Comment: Yes i wrote something else first, then used a different way, anyway remove firebaseuser check edit

Comment: Basically it works because after registering you can only get the uid. In your code you are calling getCurrentUser inside initState which is a lifecycle method and its called in the beginning (before registering), therefore you got null

Comment: Does it means, I can use all the data from the collection anywhere using users uid?

Comment: After calling the data, how to implement it in Text widget?

Comment: Please ask it as another question and add the link here so I can check it, but add details to the question (code you are using, explanation..)

Comment: Ok, I will post a new question, but before that, I will try to implement what you had written in the answer post. Anyway, thank you so much for your kindness you! :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62921547/get-user-data-from-firebase here is the question, i already tried your solution but I can't figure it out.